# how to float button on right side of column 2

Tags: html, css

I have a table like so:

```
<table id="customers">
      <caption>Services</caption> 
      
     
     <button onClick={(e) => onClickNewService()} id="record">
                        record
            </button>
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th> col1 </th>
      </tr>
      {myData.length > 0 &&
        myData.map(({ site }, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
              <Link to={"/record" + site} className='text-link'>{site}</Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  editById(site);
                }}
              >
                Edit Record
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      {myData.length === 0 && "No Data Found"}
    </table>
```

and it is currently possessing this css:

```
#record {
    float: right;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  /* background-color: #f8f8f8; */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table th,
table td {
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}
```

this css helps to specify the table structure, as well as how the table looks. I suspect that I may have to add something in here as well to fix this.

so it is floating right, but to the right of `col1`. I need it to float to the right of `col2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: HII, which element get the style of float: right;?

Comment: the button. it is currently possessing the css `float: right`

Comment: Why you don't put the button in the HTML of th>col2

Comment: just because it is formatted with lines and borders around the table, so doing so would impact the visuals of the table. The button needs to be above the table, but to the far right column (2nd). Not sure if that is possible

Comment: add position absolute to the button

Comment: doing so makes the button super wide and and not in the right position as well

Answer (score 0):

try this HTML:

```
<table id="customers">
      <caption>Services</caption> 
     
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2<button onClick={(e) => onClickrecord()} id="record">
                        Add record
            </button></th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but that doesn't work because it effects the styling of the table.

Comment: you should post the whole code for the table. this is insufficient.

Comment: just updated by question. Apologies for not doing it earlier